Chrome can't finish update
I have been using chrome on ubuntu for years without problem. Since a while, it complains it is no longer the last version. I honestly don't remember how it was installed to begin with, most likely snap or apt, but neither indicate they can do any update. Everything is up to date. I don't know, maybe it has something to do with the 24.04 update? To be clear, I updated to 24.04 a while ago.
All I have to go on is this menu button:

I don't know where to start. I don't even know how to check how it was installed. I have tried to google this but I get mostly posts from 9 years old.
Can anybody give me a few pointers, how to resolve this? Greatly appreciated!

To find out if any app is installed with snap or not the easiest way is to get snap list in terminal pls. do so and edit your question, do not write in comments, it is important that you know how chrome was installed to be able to update it.

Chrome is not a Snap App. Have you checked the Chrome site for help with this?

Here is the link for you. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/111996?hl=en

I'm not aware of google-chrome being available as a snap package as David has already stated; and its not usually installed via normal sources as google prefer it be done in other ways (thus normal apt tools don't help much) so the fix to your answer is look at how it was installed.  If it was dpkg or apt install I'd expect clues in your /var/log/apt/history.log file (but it won't tell you how or from where it was downloaded), if you used command I'd look in your BASH history, if using GUI  .... etc

Most common install is as a PPA again see the Google support site.

Thanks to David DE this was relatively painless. I uninstalled using:
sudo dpkg -r google-chrome-stable

as suggested by https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?sjid=4218456482608706824-EU#zippy=%2Clinux
I reinstalled by downloading the package from https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346#zippy=%2Clinux and installing it using standard graphical package tool. It can be selected in the filemanager. Of course this could have been done using dpkg as well.
I can also note that chromium is available in both apt and snap, but to make this sync with google services requires some more effort.

My chrome was also complaining that it wasn't up to date and says "Needs update" and/or "Finish update" in the upper right corner, which leads to telling me to download and install the latest version of chrome from a .deb file from google. I didn't want to do that thinking I might have to keep manually update/reinstall periodically. Here's what fixed it for me.

Close my open Chrome browser window(s).
Open the "Software & Updates" application.
Go to the "Other Software" tab.
Noticed that the "http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main" box was unchecked, so I enabled it.
Click Close to exit the application.

The normal Ubuntu update process then was then invoked and google-chrome-stable appeared in the list of packages to upgrade.
